# Why does the build fail with null value in the JRadioButton[] array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, netbeans, jradiobutton

The following code originally failed to build when I forgot to include

> teams[2] = new JRadioButton("RSS 1.30");

I thought that an array is created with null as the default pointer/ address.   its a simple GUI, can GUI's not be created with a null?  Or is it actually not possible/ wrong in java to leave one array position empty then fill the following one?

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class FormatFrame extends JFrame {

    JRadioButton[] teams = new JRadioButton[4];

    public FormatFrame() {
        super("Choose an Output Format");
        setSize(320, 120);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        teams[0] = new JRadioButton("Atom");
        teams[1] = new JRadioButton("RSS 0.92");
        teams[2] = new JRadioButton("RSS 1.0");
        teams[3] = new JRadioButton("RSS 2.0");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel chooseLabel = new JLabel("choose an output format for syndicated news items");
        panel.add(chooseLabel);
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        for (JRadioButton team : teams) {
            group.add(team);
            panel.add(team);
        }

        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void setLookAndFeel(){
        try{
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        FormatFrame.setLookAndFeel();
        FormatFrame ff = new FormatFrame();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> can GUI's not be created with a null?

You've just answered this for yourself when you accidentally tried it. No, you can't add a null component to a container or a ButtonGroup.

> Or is it actually not possible/ wrong in java to leave one array position empty then fill the following one?

This is quite possible, but it's what you do with the array when this happens that matters.

For instance, if you had had something like:

```
for (JRadioButton team : teams) {
    if (team != null) {
       group.add(team);
       panel.add(team);
    }
}
```

your code would probably work (but I still wouldn't use code like this since it's asking for trouble).

Comment: Thanks!  I figured it was one or the other, but wasn't sure which.  I wonder why it wouldn't just skip it or render "nothing" and move on? I guess an advantage of the build failing would be that you don't accidentally publish a class missing something major.... like a save button!